# Why is light not affected by gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, gravity, visible-light, geodesics

If a rocket needs to go to mars, it needs to go through a specific trajectory. But i can see the sun straight where it is, so light does not obey gravity?

Comment: [Deflection of starlight by the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Deflection_of_light_by_the_Sun)

Comment: [Black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole)

Comment: light is affected by gravity. before you ask 'why', you should google 'if'.

Comment: "i can see the sun straight where it is" - not quite. You see the sun where it *was* about eight minutes ago.

Comment: Light is affected by gravity in the same way as anything else is. I suggest you do a quick search on gravitational lensing which is the study of how light is bent by the gravitational pull of stars and galaxies. This is a very normal way to measure gravity in distant objects.

Comment: To everybody: the OP probably refers to Newtonian gravity, general-relativity and geodesics are tags introduced in the edit.

Comment: "*But i can see the sun straight where it is.*" This is tautological. Why do you assume what you see is the sun's true location? How are you checking the true location of the sun? With your eyes? You can't use your eyes to verify what your eyes see. Stick a straw into a glass of half full of water and observe how refraction causes the straw to appear broken. Or just look into a mirror. Are you still going to assume the objects are located where you see them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Light is obviously affected by gravity, its just that velocity of light is so tremendously huge that gravitational fields of objects like Moon, Earth or even our sun is not quite enough to "bend" light at a scale that we humans can notice it.

Our sun does bend light but it is on a very small magnitude, you cannot see it with bare eyes, you'll need a telescope for that (Einstein needed one too).
If you really wanna see a ray of light being distracted or "bent" under the influence of the gravitational field of an object, try neutron stars, quasars, pulsars or perhaps the more famous one- a black hole.
The phenomena of light being bent by gravity is known as "Gravitational Lensing".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens check this for more detail.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Light is affected by gravity. It is a known phenomenon that distant starlight can bend around an object of considerable mass.

Answer (score 1):

Light travels through a medium, the medium at which it travels through in space (or vacuum) is through the fabrics of spacetime. Matter that we are familiar with bends spacetime itself (which is what gravity is, the curvature of spacetime). Therefor, when light travels through a curved spacetime it follows that curved fabric, so that curvature (or gravity) affected the lights path.

This is what they wanted to prove for Einsteins general theory of relativity and how they did that was with a solar eclipse they've notice the light that's sort of behind the sun would curve and the best way to see it was when the Moon would black the Sun.

An easier way to show that gravity (or curved spacetime) affects light is if you had a laser shoot up to a high tower that has a detector and notice its shift in wavelength.